# Erro em passar valor json da web api para ngfor

Tags: c#, angular

Esse é o erro que está dando ao fazer a chamada da api. acha q isso é alguma coisa na saida da api ou no recebimento dela no meu outro projeto?

> ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]'
>   of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as
>   Arrays.

Codigo da web api:

```
public IList<RepresentanteConsulta> ConsultaSelect(int? cod, string type)
    {
        try
        {
            using (ISession session = SessionFactory.OpenSession())
            {
                ClienteRepository cli = new ClienteRepository();
                IDictionary<String, object> dbParameters = new Dictionary<String, object>();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.AppendLine("SELECT REPCN_REPRESENTANTE \"Codigo\", REPNM_REPRESENTANTE \"Nome\"");
                sb.AppendLine("FROM T_REPRESENTANTE REP JOIN T_REPRESENTANTE_X_CLIENTE REPCLI ON (REPCLI.ISN_REPRESENTANTE = REP.ISN_REPRESENTANTE) ");
                sb.AppendFormat("WHERE REPCLI.ISN_CLIENTE = {0} ", cod);
                return CreateSQLQuery<RepresentanteConsulta>(sb.ToString(), dbParameters);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Chamada ainda no controller web api:

```
public JsonResult SelectPesquisa(int cod, string type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case "rep":
                return Json(new { teste = representanteRepository.ConsultaSelect(cod, type) }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        return Json(new { result = "Não implementado" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Chamada no outro projeto em angular:

```
switch (type) {
        case "rep":
            params = params.set('cod', formGroup.controls['codigoCliente'].value);
            this.retornaNomeApi(NEGOCIUS_API + '/Pesquisa/SelectPesquisa', params).subscribe(res => {this.teste = res;console.log(this.teste)})
            return this.teste;
    }
```

Comment: Possivelmente você não deve ter um array.

Comment: Eu consegui resolver e realmente era na parte da api, tinha um objeto dentro de outro objeto, obrigado mesmo assim pelo comentario!!